# Netflix Metro App Desktop Shortcut Icon Missing

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, netflix, desktop-icons

I am not understanding why this would be happening and can't seem to fix it.

What it looks like:

[image]

I've tried deleting the shortcut and creating a new one and it worked once, not any more. I've also just tried uninstalling the app but it did not go away right away until I did a restart then reinstalled it - icon is still missing after making the desktop shortcut. There is a previous version dated (11.15.2015) in properties but I have not tried restoring to it - clicking open does nothing.

I create the shortcut by dragging the metro app on to the desktop. Netflix did get an update not too long ago since I can tell the UI is a little different. Other metro apps I create a desktop shortcut for do show their icon.

Comment: Thanks for stating your problem, but what do you want us to do?  Help you restore to an old version, or just find the icon?

Comment: Could the icon be found to set in properties? I just tried the restore to previous version and the icon still won't appear.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how this happened but I think you can fix it manually by right clicking on the shortcut, then Properties.
Under shortcut, click change icon and select the appropriate icon.

Comment: I would like to do that but don't know where to look since it is a metro app. It does not show up in %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll

Comment: I've found all of the related icons in the app install folder after taking control of C:\Program Files\WindowsApp\. It should be easy to set the shortcut icon in properties now.